# Yii2 MongoDB Transactions

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, transactions

I need to insert/update multiple records in multiple collections in single request. As per mongodb provides transactions now.

Can anybody please provide any working example for Yii2 MongoDb Transaction with "yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord" or way around it..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mongodb transaction is in development.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/pull/294

but you can fetch from here

https://github.com/ziaratban/yii2-mongodb/tree/transaction

i'm working on it.